# How exactly does the proxyMode parameter work in the @Scope annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-bean, cglib

I have a simple class HomeController (`singleton`) and a HomeService (`prototype`, `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`).

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private final HomeService homeService;

    public HomeController(HomeService homeService) {
        this.homeService = homeService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getHome() {
        homeService.ping();
        return "home";
    }
}


@Service
@Scope(scopeName = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class HomeService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeService.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("init HomeService");
    }

    public void ping(){
        log.info("ping ... ");
    }
}
```

Why if I make 2 requests do I get the following output to the console?

```
init HomeService
ping ... 
ping ... 

init HomeService
ping ... 
ping ...
```

Examining the previous answers on **StackOverflow**, I expect that every access to **proxy_HomeService**, causes it to access **ApplicationContext** and therefore I should get 4 different **HomeService**, I expect the following output:

```
init HomeService
ping ... 
init HomeService
ping ... 

init HomeService
ping ... 
init HomeService
ping ...
```